# How many real solutions are there to the equation $x = 1964\sin{x}-189$?

Tags: number-theory

> How many real solutions are there to the equation $x = 1964\sin{x}-189$?

**Attempt:**

Graphing $y_1=x$ and $y_2=1964\sin{x}-189$ we see that at $x = 1775$ we achieve the maximal height for $y_2$ and at $x=-2153$ the minimal height for $y_2$. We see that $a = \sin^{-1}\left({\dfrac{189}{1964}}\right) < 1$, and now we have two separate sequences of intervals $[a,a+\pi], [a+2\pi,a+3\pi],\ldots,[a+562\pi,a+563\pi]$ and $[a-\pi,a],[a-3\pi,a-2\pi],\ldots,[a-683\pi,a-682\pi]$ such that in every interval we get an intersection point.  There are a total of $282+342=624$ solutions here. We now need to add in the intervals $[a+563\pi,1775]$ and $[-2153,a-683\pi]$.

Comment: Yes, the smallest pair of roots is in $(-683\pi,-682\pi)$ and the largest in $(564\pi,565\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

rough cut -- the curves cross twice every period.
$1964*2/\pi = 1250.3\\ 1250$

$-685\pi$ almost exactly equals $-2152  (-2151.991).$

$565\pi$ almost exactly equals $1775 (1774.9998).$

Certainly, between $-685\pi$ and $565\pi$ there are 1250 points of intersection.

Does $x = 1964 \sin x - 198$ anywhere in the interval $(-2153,-685\pi)$

$y = 1964 \sin x - 198$ is strictly decreasing in the interval. Check the endpoints, and see $y$ crosses the maximum value of $x.$

$y(-685\pi) = -198, y(-2153) > -2152$, no it doesn't

1250